# Equivalent custom WCF binding for basicHttpBinding with TransportWithMessageCredential security mode

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I need to integrate my server with non-WCF client and suggested to change SOAP version in the headers. This can be done with `<textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />` element on a custom binding so i need to convert my current `basicHttpBinding`. How can i do that?

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding>
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
        </security>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

Comment: A BasicHttpBinding already contains a TextMessageEncodingBindingElement with its MessageVersion property set to `Soap11`, so your reason for needing a custom binding seems wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The custom binding definition is:

```
<customBinding>
  <binding name="basicHttpEquivalent">
    <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" />
    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
    <httpsTransport />
  </binding>
</customBinding>
```

But this binding is exactly same as the `basicHttpBinding` you mentioned.

Comment: would you happen to know where to find the custom binding equivalent for each of the standard bindings?  I think I am going to require this to be able to use the enableUnsecureResponse attribute.  Thanks, Rich

Comment: @Richard: I'm using Reflector but you can try [BindingBox](http://webservices20.cloudapp.net/).